# Error on typedef struct. before '*' token

Tags: c, struct, typedef

The compiler is gcc and I'm using an old version of linux

```
typedef struct strlist strlist;

struct strlist
{
    char *data;
    time_t *timestamp;
    struct strlist *next;
}

strlist * list_directory(char *dirname)
{
//do something
}
```

The error message is:

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

and it's on the line:

```
strlist * list_directory(char *dirname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct strlist
{
    char *data;
    time_t *timestamp;
    struct strlist *next;
};
^^^
 |
```

You are missing the `;` at the end of structure declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the struct declaration with a semicolon. That tripped me up so many times when I started programming in C...